# Adding at the End

Tags: java

Thank you for taking the time to read this, I'm currently taking a Java class and the professor told us that a good practice to understand links would be to make a doubly linked list. I have made a singly linked list but I am having trouble converting it to a doubly linked list. The problem I am having is I'm trying to add a number to the end of the list but when I try to add a new number to the end it just shows that numbers and not the others. I think I'm just creating a new list and displaying that but I'm not sure. An example of code would be really appreciated.

Normal Add Code:

```
 public void add(int element){

            Node n = new Node();
            n.setItem(element);
            n.setNext(head); 
            n.setBefore(null); 
            if(head != null) {

                head.setBefore(n); 
            }
            head = n;

        }
```

The add to last code:

```
public void addLast(int element) {

        Node currentNode = head;


        currentNode.setItem(element);
        currentNode.setBefore(tail); 
        currentNode.setNext(null);


        tail = currentNode;

    }
```

FULL CODE:

```
public class DoubleLink {

private Node head; 
private Node tail;

    //Methods
    //Constructors
    public DoubleLink(){
        head = null;
        tail = null;

    }

    public void add(int element){

            Node n = new Node();
            n.setItem(element);
            n.setNext(head); 
            n.setBefore(null); 
            if(head != null) {

                head.setBefore(n); 
            head = n;


        }
    public void display(){      //LIST TRAVERSAL!
        // Reference traversal
        //Needed an interatior
        Node currentNode = head;
        while(currentNode != null){
            System.out.print(currentNode.getItem()+ " ");
            currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }


    public int search(int element){
        int position = 0;
        Node currentNode = head;
        while(currentNode != null){
            if(currentNode.getItem() == element){
                return position;

            }
            position++;
            currentNode = currentNode.getNext();

        }
        return -1;
    }

    public void insert(int element, int position){
        int currentposition = 0;
        Node currentNode = head;

        //Traverse to the right position
        while(currentposition < position-1){

            currentposition++;
        } 
        Node n = new Node();
        n.setItem(element);
        n.setNext(currentNode.getNext());
        currentNode.setNext(n);

        //The previous number connecting to the new number
        currentNode = tail;

    }

    public void remove(int position){
        int currentposition = 0;
        Node currentNode = head;

        //Traverse to the right position
        while(currentposition < position-1){

            currentposition++;
        }

        Node dyingNode = currentNode.getNext();
        currentNode.setNext(dyingNode.getNext());


    }

    public void addLast(int element) {



        Node nodeToInsert = new Node();
        nodeToInsert.setItem(element);
        nodeToInsert.setBefore(tail); 
        nodeToInsert.setNext(null);

        if(tail != null)
          tail.setNext(nodeToInsert); //link the list

        tail = nodeToInsert; //now the tail is the new node i added

        if(head == null)       // if the list has no elements then set the head
             head = nodeToInsert;


    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    DoubleLink l = new DoubleLink();


    l.add(1);
    l.add(2);
    l.add(3);
    l.display();
    l.addLast(99);
    l.display();

    }
}
```

Node Class:

```
public class Node {

    //Data

    private int item;
    private Node next;
    private Node before;

    //Methods
    public int getItem(){
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(int item){
        this.item = item;
    }

    public Node getNext(){
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext (Node next){
        this.next = next;
    }

    public Node getBefore(){
        return before;
    }

    public void setBefore(Node before){
        this.before = before;
    }

}
```

Comment: You are not creating a new node when you add a tail. You should create a new node, and then make it the new tail. Just like when you add an element at the beginning, there you create a new node and replace the old head with the new node. Well, now, notice that there is no ```new``` keyworkd in yor ```addlast``` method. So, you are not creating new nodes there.

Comment: in addLast you have to create a new Node too.. not setting to the head..

Comment: For your own benefit, you should write out what you want to do in pseudo code. Also, you should give an example of what your test scenario is, and what your expected behavior is and what your actual behavior is.

Comment: @ CodeThulhu: I have written the pseudo code, I written it even twice and I get the logic behind it its just the coding for some reason just doesn't come to me.

Comment: @RogelioLoop - I put it to you that you either *don't* get the logic behind it, or your pseudo-code is too high-level.

Comment: @Edwin Dalorzo: Oh, so I need to create a new Node to add it to the tail. Ok, I need to create a  new Node to make it for the add last method.

Comment: @Nachokk: Ok, I think I understand what I need to do. So once making a new node I need to connect it to tail in the add last method.

Comment: @Stephen C: Maybe I need to redo it or something, maybe it is too high level because I understand the logic behind it when a new Node is introduced to the list.

Comment: @RogelioLoop Correct, you are "adding" a node, and you just want it to be the new tail. So, you make the old tail point to the new node (i.e. link the old tail to the new node), and then place the tail on the new node (i.e. ```tail = newNode```).

Comment: @RogelioLoop you can check the answer that user provides and comment there.

Comment: @Nachokk: Thank you, thats what I'm currently trying to do yet I am still getting the same issue with me just getting the same numbers without the new one.

Comment: @Dalorzo: I see, so would it be something similar to what they are posting below? I have just tried  those codes but I am getting the same results with showing the same list but the new still doesn't show up.

Comment: @nachokk: I have just put it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change your code, creating a `new Node()` like this.

```
public void addLast(int element) {

        Node nodeToInsert = new Node();
        nodeToInsert.setItem(element);
        nodeToInsert.setBefore(tail); 
        nodeToInsert.setNext(null);

        if(tail != null)
          tail.setNext(nodeToInsert); //link the list

        tail = nodeToInsert; //now the tail is the new node i added

        if(head == null)       // if the list has no elements then set the head
             head = nodeToInsert;
}
```

**UPDATE**

The problem is in your add method , you are not setting never `tail`

```
public void add(int element){

            Node n = new Node();
            n.setItem(element);
            n.setNext(head); 
            n.setBefore(null); 
            if(head != null) 
                head.setBefore(n); 
            else{
                tail=n; // if head == null then now you have an element so head = tail
            }

            head = n;        
    }
```

Comment: I tried this but it just gets me the same results out without the number I added which I don't know why since this seems like it would work. Maybe there is something wrong with the set up I have or maybe I'm just not showing the tail part?

Comment: @RogelioLoop you should provide then a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) of your implementation, cause this have to work.

Comment: I agree it should work but I don't know why it is not working. I read the SSCCE and I never heard of this and from what I read should I post the rest of the code? Maybe to see if there any mistake or something?

Comment: @RogelioLoop Exactly, always if is short concise and self contained

Comment: Thank you for telling me, I just edited it into the problem. That is the full code besides the Node class which is just the set and get functions and such.

Comment: Post node class too.. then people just can copy paste your code and test it. for exmaple put it in the same file as `private class Node{ //code }`

Comment: I posted it in a different file as Node.Java in the same project. Thats the way people have told me to do it but maybe thats what is affecting my code.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working now. So the problem was with my add? I never set tail so equal the n. So that was my issue.

Comment: @RogelioLoop the `add` and `addLast` both of them, you always have to take care with `edges cases`. As an advice before programming this things i always make the algorithm in paper on **WHAT** i have to do, making graphics to be more clear, cause then in code you make get confused. Glad to help, keep coding!

Comment: I understand, the edge cases weren't being used correctly and such, they were left hanging in a way. I think I understand what my errors where then.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
public void addLast(int element) {

    Node newNode = new Node();

    newNode.setItem(element);
    newNode.setNext(null);
    newNode.setBefore(tail);

    tail.setNext(newNode);

    tail = newNode;
}
```

Comment: For this code I get an error message "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException".

Answer (score 1):

In addlast(int element) you are not creating memory for new node you just overwriting in the 
head node.
So, your code goes like this

```
public void addlist(int element)
{
    Node currentNode = new node();


    currentNode.setItem(element);
    currentNode.setBefore(tail); 
    currentNode.setNext(null);
    if(tail!=null)
         tail.setNext(currentNode);


    tail = currentNode;
}
```

Comment: I just tried this but it doesn't show the new number it shows the name list once more without the new number.